# Search for a valid ip address in a JSON file and grab it

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to look for an IP address in the file I receive. Can I just grab the IP address from the JSON just by removing everything else? What is the best method to grab this string?

Code:

```
if data['secret'] == "acoolsecret":
  print (data['ip'])
  for element in data['ip']:
        if element['ip'] == 'ip_addresss:':
            print 'there'
            break
    else:
        print 'IP NOT FOUND'
  return ("Secret Correct, continuing with program STATUS:200")
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"ip": "gateway: 1.1.0.0\\nip_address: 8.8.8.8\\nnetmask: 255.255.240.0\\ntype: public", "secret": "acoolsecret"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by modifying the code provided by @caverac. I'll paste the code here so that anyone can see the solution.

```
 datatmp=json.loads(request.data)
 datatmp=datatmp['ip']
 datatmp=datatmp.split('\n')
 datatmp=datatmp[1]
 ip=datatmp[12:]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but if you do this

```
>>> d = {y[0].strip() : y[1].strip() for y in [x.split(':') for x in data['ip'].split('\\n')]}
>>> d.get('ip_address')
'8.8.8.8'
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick reply, this would work if the sample JSON had not been parsed. Furthermore, my JSON gets sent as bytes and is therefore represented as so: b'JSONHERE'